# Синхронизация потоков WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

Создаю я второй поток для расчетов параллельных, расчеты в цикле. В итоге, чтобы после итерации добавить данные в таблицу основного потока, вызываю `BeginInvoke`

```
for (int i = 0; i < paramOptFirst.Count; i++)
            {
                  wnd.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => wnd.dataGrid.Items.Add(new ResultData(Timeframe, startDateOpt + " -- " + endDateOpt, startDateFrwd + " -- " + endDateFrwd, resultOptOne[i][0], resultOptOne[i][1], resultOptOne[i][2], resultOptOne[i][3], resultOptOneF[i][0], resultOptOneF[i][1], resultOptOneF[i][2], resultOptOneF[i][3], paramOptFirst[i]))));

            }
```

Но проблема в том, что пока основной поток пытается добавить в таблицу данные, поток для расчетов эти данные уже успевает обнулить и приступить к новому расчету. Тут и выскакивает, что пытаюсь добавить `paramOptFirst[i]`, когда его уже обнулили и в итоге получаю исключение. Как можно заставить поток расчетов вначале подождать, пока выполнится функцию BeginInvoke?

Comment: Используйте Invoke вместо BeginInvoke

Comment: осильте MVVM и не мучайте себя подобным кодом.